# Deny access to subfolders of Cloudfoundry app

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

Im running a Cloudfoundry app without any troubles. However, subfolders and their files are exposed and accessible simply by adding it to the URL -> for example /lang/fr.json.

Is there any way to prevent direct access to such subfolders for Cloudfundry apps? On a regular Apache server, I'd activate **mod_rewrite** to automatically route back to the index file of my app.

Thanks!

Comment: This is dependent on what buildpack you use. Can you give a bit mor details on what your app actually is and what buildpack you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: I'm using the standard Cloud Foundry buildpack for PHP. In the `options.json` file, I pass the parameter `"HTTPD_VERSION":"2.4"`.

With Apache 2.4 installed, I can simply place a `.htaccess` file in the folder I want to protect. The file only needs the content `Require all denied`.